# Can't open RStudio thru x2go

Tags: remote, remote-desktop, x2go, rstudio

I have two computers on two different networks, which I will call Server and Client. Server and Client both run Debian 9.5 and have x2go installed.

When I'm on Client machine, I use x2go to connect to Server machine. On Server, when I try to run `rstudio`.

```
The X11 connection broke: Maximum allowed requested length exceeded (code 4)
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":50.0"
      after 421 requests (421 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Can I bypass this error to run RStudio from Client via x2go?

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution to using Rstudio with X2Go, but there are two alternative solutions:

- The `remoter` R package on CRAN allows connecting a client to a remote R session. This does not even need RStudio, though it can be used with it.
- `rstudio-server` can be installed on the server and then users (local or remote) can log in to a session on a browser. Additionally, if you don't want to open port 8787, you can use ssh tunneling.